# Creating legend around html INPUT box, not fieldset

Tags: html, forms, input, legend, fieldset

I would like to create a legend directly on a normal html input box. When you create a normal input with type text for example, html automatically creates a box with a border for this input. If I add a fieldset and legend tag to this input field, another box is create around it. I would like my legend to look like the attached picture [image attached below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96JNj.png) from the site https://jiji.com.gh/registration.html.

I tried to do this by removing the border around the input field using css like so:

```
.signup-form input  {
border: 0px;
```

}

and HTML:

```
<form class=signup-form>
<fieldset>
<legend>Enter email</legend>
<input type="email" name="emailaddress">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

But this creates a much bigger box than I would like, although it actually produces what I'm trying to do. Any better ideas on how I can do this to have a neat form with legend like used on the site I mentioned?

Comment: why not just use a label and position it where you want with css (and give it the same background colour as the page).

Comment: @Pete Label looks so old fashioned. I'd rather use a placeholder. But good idea thanks.

Comment: label tag makes it more accessible

Comment: @Pete this is true. I guess simple is always better. I don't need to reinvent the wheel.